# How would I check if a word or sentence is a palindrome?

Tags: python

I am supposed to check if a word or sentence is a palindrome using code, and I was able to check for words, but I'm having trouble checking sentences as being a palindrome. Here's my code, it's short but I'm not sure how else to add it to check for sentence palindromes. I'm sort of a beginner at python, and I've already looked at other people's code, and they are too complicated for me to **really** understand. Here's what I wrote:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
  if s[::1] == s[::-1]:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Here is an example of a sentence palindrome: "Red Roses run no risk, sir, on nurses order." (If you ignore spaces and special characters)

Comment: what is a sentence palindrome? you mean we ignore spaces and treat all letters as a big word?

Comment: This only checks the first and last characters, but not anything else in between. Please post the code with which you were `able to check for words` that were palindromes

Comment: Yeah, that's basically it. Here's an example: 'Red Roses run no risk, sir, on nurses order.' I'm supposed to get rid of any special characters and spaces in order to see if it's a palindrome

Comment: @inspectorG4dget You sure about that? ;)

Comment: Try removing all the spaces, suddenly your sentence is effectively a word.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono Just removing spaces won't work on the example the OP just posted in a comment.

Comment: @PM2Ring: damn! I need some sleep

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @PM2Ring Right. Remove spaces. toLowerCase(), skip punctuation. Good eyes.

Comment: This would detect a sentence such as "So patient a doctor to doctor a patient so" or "You can cage a swallow, can't you, but you can't swallow a cage, can you?"

Comment: BTW, `s[::1]` just makes a copy of `s`, so you might as well just use `s` here. And you don't need that `if`. This is shorter and clearer: `return s == s[::-1]`.

Answer (score 8):

```
import string

def is_palindrome(s):
    whitelist = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
    s = s.lower()
    s = ''.join([char for char in s if char in whitelist])
    return s == s[::-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

To check sentence palindrome-ness, the algorithm seems to be:

1. Remove any non-alphabetical character
2. Compare `new_s` to `new_s[::-1]` case-insensitively.

You can do the former by doing:

```
import string

valid = set(string.ascii_letters)
result_s = ''.join([ch for ch in original_s if ch in valid])
```

Then the latter by doing:

```
result_s.casefold() == result_s.casefold()[::-1]
```

Put the whole thing together with:

```
import string

s = "Red roses run no risk, sir, on nurses order"
s2 = "abcba"
s_fail = "blah"

def is_palindrome(s):
    valid = set(string.ascii_letters)
    result_s = ''.join([ch for ch in s if ch in valid])
    cf_s = result_s.casefold()
    return cf_s == cf_s[::-1]

assert(is_palindrome(s))
assert(is_palindrome(s2))
assert(is_palindrome(s_fail))  # throws AssertionError
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the string to get only the letters like this:

```
letters = ''.join(c for c in words if c in string.letters)
is_palindrome(letters)
```

You would also have to call `lower` on it:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    s = ''.join(c for c in s if c in string.letters)
    s = s.lower()
    return s == s[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title, sentence could be termed as palindrome in 2 ways:

1. **Order of words should be inverted**: Create list of words and check for the inverted list:

   ```
   >>> my_sentence = 'Hello World Hello'
   >>> words = my_sentence.split()
   >>> words == words[::-1]
   True
   ```
2. **Order of characters should be inverted**: Check for the inverted strings:

   ```
   >>> my_sentence = 'Hello World Hello'
   >>> my_sentence == my_sentence[::-1]
   False
   ```

What you want is the way 2, with the exception that your code should discard commas `,` and white-space . And also it should be case insensitive. Firstly remove spaces and commas using `str.replace()`,  and convert the string to lower using `str.lower()`. Then make the inverted check as:

```
>>> my_sentence = 'Red Roses run no risk, sir, on nurses order'
>>> my_sentence = my_sentence.replace(' ', '').replace(',', '').lower()
>>> my_sentence == my_sentence[::-1]
True
```

Comment: `is_palindrome("Red Roses run no risk, sir, on nurses order") == True` says the comment in the question.

Comment: Updated the answer based on comment

Answer (score 0):

If by palindrome sentence you mean ignoring spaces, you can do that like this:

```
is_palindrome(sentence.replace(' ', ''))
```

Comment: The example sentence has commas.

Answer (score 0):

Without for:

```
word_pilandrom = str(input("Please enter a word: "))
    new_word=word_pilandrom.lower().replace(" ","")
    if new_word[::1] == new_word[::-1]:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("NOT")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str =input("Enter the word")
s =str.lower()
s1 =s.split(" ")
s2 =s1.join()
s3 =''.join(reversed(s2))
if s2 ==s3 :
   print("Palindrome:")
else :
  print("Not Palindrome:")
```

Comment: This question already contains multiple answers. Can you explain (by editing your answer) where your answer differs from the other answers? Also know that Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

We need to check whether the reverse of a string equals the original string with two additional requirements:

- ignore case
- ignore anything except letters

The solution is:

1. Convert all letters to the same case (e.g. lower case)
2. Filter only letters
3. Check palindrome condition

```py
    def is_palindrome(s):
        s_lower = s.lower()
        letters = [ch for ch in s_lower if ch.isalpha()]
        return letters == letters[::-1]
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_